# Draggable content going underneath editable div?

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

Trying to get the draggable image to drop into the content editable div. For some reason the draggable image goes underneath the content editable div.
I can supply more info if needed to figure it out like css html jquery files.

Here is a two second video showing you what i am talking about.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wESXVkfDUzE

Thanks, any help would be awesome.

Comment: It would be easier to help if the issue in question was added to a jsFiddle. But from the video it looks to be an issue with the z-index in your css

Comment: Yeah it was a z:index problem. Did not realize i had any elements set with a zindex. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`draggable` has both a `stack` option and a `zIndex` option.

One of those two will fix your issue.

API Refrence: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack